# Renaming multiple feature layers for multiple MXDs using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, layers, data-source

I have recently renamed 20 feature layers that are currently saved in approximately 100 MXDs. To fix the broken data source as a result of changing the name, I am using the following code:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"//test.mxd") #file path for mxd
  for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
   if str(lyr.name)=="original":
     lyr.replaceDataSource(r"//test.gdb", "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", "new") #file path for geodatabase
print("Success")
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

However, this code means that I have to update one MXD at a time.

Is there a way I can add into this code that I would like it to check multiple MXDs for the same layers and replace with the same new data name?

Comment: BERA has already provided the framework. Your code just needs to be indented inside it. I would recommend creating a `.bak` copy of the previous document before saving over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List the mxd:s using os.walk. I have not tried this with your code, test it on one mxd copy first.

This will list all mxd files in mxdfolder, including any subfolders:

```
import os, arcpy

mxdfolder = r'C:\your_folder'

for root, folder, files in os.walk(mxdfolder):
    for file in files:
        fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
        if os.path.isfile(fullname) and file.endswith('.mxd'):
            print fullname
            #do something with fullname (which is a full path to a mxd document)
            mxd = fullname
            #The rest of your code goes here
```